# Get the non-null object from within the child objects of a class

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class called SchoolStaff and it contains a few child class objects like:

```
public class SchoolStaff
{
    public JuniorStaff? juniorStaff { get; set; }

    public SeniorStaff? seniorStaff { get; set; }

    public AdministrativeStaff? administrativeStaff { get; set; }
}

public class AdministrativeStaff
{
    public int administrativeStaffId { get; set; }
}

public class SeniorStaff
{
    public int seniorStaffId { get; set; }
}

public class JuniorStaff
{
    public int juniorStaffId { get; set; }
}
```

Now, out of these three objects in SchoolStaff, there can always be one object only that contains a value, rest of the two are null. I want to fetch the object which is not null.

Is there a way to do this by using LINQ/Reflection?

N.B. The code presented is an example to demonstrate the scenario only.

Comment: You could access it like this: `object staff = schoolStaff.juniorStaff ?? schoolStaff.seniorStaff ?? schoolStaff.administrativeStaff!`. However, if this example resembles your actual code, a redesign is the better way to go.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the code is not real world design example but rather just to explain what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property which checks which of your other properties is not null and returns that property:

```
public class SchoolStaff
    {
        public JuniorStaff? juniorStaff { get; set; }

        public SeniorStaff? seniorStaff { get; set; }

        public AdministrativeStaff? administrativeStaff { get; set; }

        public object NotNullStaff
        {
        get
           {
           if(juniorStaff != null) return juniorStaff;
           if(seniorStaff != null) return seniorStaff;
           if(administrativeStaff != null) return administrativeStaff;
           throw new InvalidOperationExcpetion("at least one property must not be null!");
           }
        }
    }
```

If you have a lot of properties or they change often, reflection can be better. But be aware that reflection has slow performance, which might be a problem if you access that property very often. The version with reflection looks like this:

```
public object NotNullStaff
{
  get
  {
     return GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.Name != nameof(NotNullStaff))
        .Select(x => x.GetValue(this))
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x != null);
  }
}
```

Online-demo of the version with reflection: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oEviz2

Comment: The reflection example might work now, but it's extremely brittle and should be avoided for reasons other than performance. It violates the open-closed principle, because adding a new property of an unrelated type e.g. string would break the program at runtime.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I've tested the reflection example with a couple of possible scenarios that can happen with this client based domain model and no it doesn't break at run time. I can only agree that using reflection is a very expensive deal. But given the limitations in domain model and what we can do with it, this seems to be the solution for now. The rest has to be a case for advocating a redesign. 
Thank you for your inputs :)

Answer (score 1):

I provide a different way to store your *staff* avoiding your issue:

```
public class SchoolStaff
{
    public SchoolStaff(IStaff staff)
    {
        Staff = staff;
    }

    public IStaff Staff { get; set; }
}

public enum StaffType
{
    Junior,
    Senior,
    Administrative
}

public interface IStaff
{
    public int StaffId { get; }
    public StaffType Type { get; }
}

public class AdministrativeStaff: IStaff
{
    public AdministrativeStaff(int staffId)
    {
        StaffId = staffId;
    }

    public int StaffId { get; }
    public StaffType Type => StaffType.Administrative;
}

public class SeniorStaff: IStaff
{
    public SeniorStaff(int staffId)
    {
        StaffId = staffId;
    }

    public int StaffId { get; }
    public StaffType Type => StaffType.Senior;
}

public class JuniorStaff: IStaff
{
    public JuniorStaff(int staffId)
    {
        StaffId = staffId;
    }

    public int StaffId { get; }
    public StaffType Type => StaffType.Junior;
}
```

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: i just wanted to provide an easy way to avoid the issue because it seems that 2 are always null and 1 is available means that he abuses the SchoolStaff class for a missing StaffType. Of course there are multiple ways like a generic SchoolStaff or whatever, but i wanted to keep it simple. SchoolStaff could still have other properties related to school, but you're right, with the code provided this is just a wrapper and it seems to have no other purpose( so `IStaff` is all he needs).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for your answer. This is definitely something on similar lines, as your solution, for the redesign phase later on (if we get to that point).